# asyncio whether to support tracking lines to a specific timeout

Tags: python

I want to trace the line where asyncio times out
eg :await asyncio.sleep(100000)

```
import asyncio

async def eternity():
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print('yay!')


async def eternity2():
    await asyncio.sleep(100000)
    print('yay2!')

async def dowork():
    await eternity()
    await eternity2()
    return 1


async def main():
    try:
        await asyncio.wait_for(dowork(), timeout=2)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError: # ######## i want Traceback which line times out
        print('timeout!')
        raise

asyncio.run(main())
```

asyncio Whether to provide a reason to get a specific timeout  and Trace to a specific line！！！！！！！！！！！！！！！！！！！！！！！！

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the traceback module? For example

```
import traceback

try:
    int("bla")
except Exception as e:
    traceback.print_tb(e.__traceback__)
```

Outputs:

```
File "<ipython-blabla>", line 5, in <module>
    int("bla")
```